# How to install and build CodeIntel with Pip for Sublime Text

Tags: python, pip, sublimetext3, sublimecodeintel

I'm trying to install [CodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/CodeIntel) on my Mac for use with [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel), but I'm getting an error.

I'm running:

- MacOS Sierra (10.12.5)
- Python 2.7.10
- PIP 9.0.1

When I run:

```
pip install --upgrade --pre CodeIntel
```

I get:

```
Installing collected packages: inflector, clang, setuptools, zope.cachedescriptors, esprima, cmdln, chardet, appdirs, six, applib, 3to2, CodeIntel
  Running setup.py install for inflector ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-4PggyB/inflector/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-cwF3dg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/inflector
    copying inflector/__init__.py -> build/lib/inflector
    running egg_info
    writing Inflector.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to Inflector.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to Inflector.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'Inflector.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'Inflector.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    creating build/lib/inflector/languages
    copying inflector/languages/__init__.py -> build/lib/inflector/languages
    copying inflector/languages/base.py -> build/lib/inflector/languages
    copying inflector/languages/english.py -> build/lib/inflector/languages
    copying inflector/languages/spanish.py -> build/lib/inflector/languages
    running install_lib
    creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/inflector
    copying build/lib/inflector/__init__.py -> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/inflector
    creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/inflector/languages
    copying build/lib/inflector/languages/__init__.py -> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/inflector/languages
    copying build/lib/inflector/languages/base.py -> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/inflector/languages
    copying build/lib/inflector/languages/english.py -> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/inflector/languages
    copying build/lib/inflector/languages/spanish.py -> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/inflector/languages
    byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/inflector/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
    byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/inflector/languages/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
    byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/inflector/languages/base.py to base.pyc
    byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/inflector/languages/english.py to english.pyc
    byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/inflector/languages/spanish.py to spanish.pyc
    running install_data
    copying README.md -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/
    error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/README.md'
```

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-4PggyB/inflector/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-cwF3dg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-4PggyB/inflector/
```